# Change User Agent to Mobile on Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, testing

I am trying to test a SP version of view on Laravel Dusk.

I use [jenssegers/agent](https://github.com/jenssegers/agent) to switch views to render on my controllers.

Is there any way to change user agent when running Laravel Dusk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might want to override `TestCase::driver` function like this:

```
protected function driver()
{
    // iPhone 6, for instance
    $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1';
    $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
    $options = new ChromeOptions;
    $options->setExperimentalOption('mobileEmulation', ['userAgent' => $ua]);

    return RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://localhost:9515', $options->toCapabilities()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the answer of massan is partial correct but not really give an example which should be like this :

```
    <?php

    namespace Tests\Browser;
    use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
    use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
    use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;

    use Tests\DuskTestCase;
    use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;


    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

    class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
    {

        private $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36';

        /**
         * A Dusk test example.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function testExample()
        {

            $this->browse(function (Browser $browser ) {
                $browser->visit('https://www.whatismybrowser.com/');
            dd("Stop");

            });
        }

        protected function driver()
        {
            $ua = $this->ua;
            $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
            $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
                '--disable-gpu',
               // '--headless',
                '--force-device-scale-factor=0.8',
                '--window-size=1920,1080',
            ]);
            $options->setExperimentalOption('mobileEmulation', ['userAgent' => $ua]);

            return RemoteWebDriver::create(
                'http://localhost:9515', $options->toCapabilities()

            );

        }
}
```